# c++ random number duplicate prevent

Tags: c++

I've got a random number generator function ("Rndom (min, max)"),
and I have an int with 4 elements called "Data [3]".
I used the for loop to generate numbers (1-4) to the elements of the "Data" int:

```
for (int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
{
    Data[i] = Rndom(1, 4)
}
```

How can I prevent that the data gets duplicated element number ? 
So, I don't want this: "Data" elements: 1 3 4 1 ("1" is duplicated). I want to make different numbers....

Thank you for the help !

Comment: You could just put all numbers in a vector and do a shuffle. The example here shows that: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Comment: Does your array always have the same size as the number range?

Comment: off topic: `Data [3]` will not contain 4 elements.

Comment: Data [0] is an element too....

Comment: ***Data [0] is an element too*** Correct, so is Data [1] and Data [2] but not Data [3] which is out of bounds. So you have only 3 elements.

Comment: Nope, it is four element: 0,1,2,3

Answer (score 4):

Since you want an array or vector of shuffled integer values, use `std::shuffle` to shuffle a vector (or whatever) initialized with sequential values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rng(rd());                       // seed rng using rd
    std::vector<int> data(3);                     // create a 3-entry vector
    std::iota(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);       // fill with sequence
    std::shuffle(data.begin(), data.end(), rng);  // mix entries using rng
    // dump the result
    for(auto r : data) { std::cout << r << ' '; }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The outputs of 3 executions:

`1 0 2`

`2 1 0`

`2 0 1`

Here is a version which doesn't rely so much on the standard C++ library, and uses the C-runtime's crappy random number generator, just because I didn't have access to Rndom's source code, which is undoubtedly of a proprietary nature, so this is quite understandable:

```
#include <iostream>  // only for std::cout
#include <cstdlib>   // for srand, rand
#include <ctime>     // for time

namespace shuffle {
    using size_t = decltype(sizeof(1));

    bool Srndom() {
        std::srand(std::time(0));
        return true;
    }

    int Rndom(int low, int high) {
        static bool init = Srndom();
        return std::rand() % (high - low + 1) + low;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void Shuffle(T* pdata, size_t N) {
        for(size_t i=0; i<N-1; ++i) {
            const int swap_idx = Rndom(i, N-1);
            if(swap_idx != i) {
                const T t = pdata[i];
                pdata[i] = pdata[swap_idx];
                pdata[swap_idx] = t;
            }
        }
    }

    template <typename T, size_t N>
    void Shuffle(T (&data)[N]) {
        Shuffle(data, N);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void Series(T* pdata, size_t N, T start) {
        for(size_t i=0; i<N; ++i) {
            pdata[i] = start++;
        }
    }

    template <typename T, size_t N>
    void Series(T (&data)[N], T start) {
        Series(data, N, start);
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace shuffle;

    int Data[4];     // I guess you actually want 4
    Series(Data, 1); // and maybe to start at 1.
    Shuffle(Data);   // Shuffle Data's entries.

    // Dump Data's entries
    for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(Data)/sizeof(Data[0]); ++i) {
        std::cout << Data[i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The outputs of 3 executions (over 1 second apart):

`2 3 1 4`

`4 2 3 1`

`2 4 3 1`

Comment: lol you didn't used my function..... Bro, this is not a windows program.... I am programming a game which doesn't have such thing like "include vector....etc."

Comment: Haha, you're funny.  But I will go ahead and humor you with the answer you want, using my best guess at an implementation of `Rndom` and a statically-allocated array.  Hang on...

Comment: ***I am programming a game which doesn't have such thing like "include vector....etc."*** You tagged your question as `c++`. std::vector is part of the standard library in `c++`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` or `set` to store the numbers generated and avoid duplication.

```
set<int> s;
for (int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
{
   int x;
   for(;;)
   {
      int x = Rndom(1, 4) ;

      if(s.find(x)==s.end()) 
      {
         s.insert(x);
         Data[i]=x;
         // consider it ..it is not duplicate
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Also you can use [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/?kw=set) or [unordered_set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/?kw=unordered_set) to realize the same thing.

The reason of using `set` over `map` is `std::sets` contain only the key, while in `std::map` there is an associated value.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat.: Actually I thought of something different thats why I answered that way and anyway I just wanted OP to give an idea of how to use ...modified as per the full requiremment.

Comment: Thanks, but where I do you use the "i" int in the for loop ? You just using "x" int.

Comment: You were using i for indexing purpose right? Then use where you are inserting `x` into the set... @Vettel.Sebastian

Comment: Is there any way to do this with int block like in my code ?

Comment: @Vettel.Sebastian.: You can just add that statement...what you want state clearly pls

Comment: I want to do this without using vector......  I want to use "Data[i]"

Comment: I haven't used vector ..just used `set`

Comment: Oh thanks for the edit... :D I just need to put "Data[i] = x"

Comment: I changed you script to this: http://pastebin.com/Acipvt6X you think it will work ?

Comment: @Vettel.Sebastian.: HHere in case your elelment is found in set then you will not do anything and just go to next iteration if for loop...that's why I added that `for(;;) loop`

Comment: Ok, and what should I write to the "for( ; ; )" ? (?;?;?)

Comment: @Vettel.Sebastian.: You just want to store the random numbers somewhere right? Then whenever you isert something in set just push it in array too like I did in my code

Comment: Damn... I don't understand this. I want to have Data[ 3 elements 1-4 without duplicate] Thats all.

Comment: @Vettel.Sebastian.: It is done here in this code..just write the code and print it..